# Is loan repayment a red flag for visit visa even if I provide evidence of funds for the trip?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm going to apply for PLAB-2 visit visa with 3 months statement of my salary account.
I took a loan 6 months ago for Business purpose and monthly repayment is deducted from my account.The Business is running and covers about half of my montly living expenses.
And to finance my PLAB-2 trip, I sold Some Gold, which I have already declared on my tax returns, and deposited that money into my salary account.
So I can provide evidence for everything but I'm worried about rejection because it's very complicated as you can see.
I'm looking for honest opinion if I should ahead with visa application or build a separate statement.
My whole career hangs on this exam so I'm scared and worried.

Comment: The usual advice given on this site is to explain everything to them. Do not worry about it being complicated, they understand. The last thing you want to do is to have sums of money which have no attached explanation. God luck with the PLAB.